# FileNotFoundException while getting file from resources folder using getResource()

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I need to get this file from the resources folder in the File object, not in InputSream.
I am using below code, working file on eclipse but FoleNotFoundException on the server. )Using AWS EC2)

Code:

```java
    URL res = ResidentHelperService.class.getClassLoader().getResource("key.pem");
                System.out.println("resource path2  :" + res);          
    File privateKeyFile = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
```

After printing path looks like:

> :jar:file:/home/centos/myproject/microservices/user-service/target/user-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/project-common-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/key.pem

I have added dependency on the common jar to user service pom.

Please help me to get the file from resources of a common project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your file in `resources` folder, the easiest way to access it from the code is probably to use `org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils` class that Spring provides:

```
try {
    final File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:key.pem");
    ....
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Perhaps this way can help you with your issue.